# Duplex printing, Brother DCP 7065DN, (K)ubuntu 14.10

Tags: printing, brother

How can I do duplex printing on a Brother DCP-7065DN printer in Kubuntu 14.10?  When I install the printer as a new printer, there are three eligible choices among the Brother drivers: "DCP-7065DN (brlaser3)" and "DCP7065DN" (twice).  Which one works?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the duplex problem using the Driver Install Tool in Ubuntu 16.04. The tool will install LPR, CUPSwrapper driver and scanner driver (for scanner models).

- Configure your router and give your printer a static IP-address.
- Download linux-brprinter-installer-[version].gz from [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp7065dn_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625&dlang=true)
- Run in terminal:

  ```
  gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-[version].gz
  sudo su
  bash linux-brprinter-installer-[version] 'DCP-7065DN'
  ```
- When asked "Will you specify the DeviceURI?":

  - USB Users: Choose N (No)
  - Network Users: Choose Y (Yes) and give DeviceURI (static IP-address)
- After installation you'll find DCP-7065DN duplex settings in:

> System Settings -> Printers -> DCP7065DN -> Properties ->
>
> > Printer Options -> Duplex: DuplexTumble / DuplexNoTumble / None
> >
> > Job Options -> Common Options -> More -> Sides: one-sided / two-sided-long-edge / two-sided-short-edge.

Answer (score 0):

The first copy of DCP7065DN worked for me.  Of course there shouldn't be three choices of the same printer in the first place, and I hope someone fixes that.